# `TERM` environment variable not exported from `.profile`?

Tags: environment-variables, .profile, virtual-terminal

I have this in my `.profile` (I'm running Ubuntu 12.04):

```
export TERM="xterm-256color"
```

The variable seems not exported or be invariably later overwritten as `TERM="xterm"`.

A test with Gnome Terminal:

```
$ gnome-terminal --command=sh
$ echo $TERM
> xterm

$ gnome-terminal --command=bash
$ echo $TERM
> xterm

$ gnome-terminal --command=zsh
$ echo $TERM
> xterm
```

At least, this is not due to the shell. Is this due to `gnome-terminal`?

Another test with Xterm:

```
$ xterm sh
$ echo $TERM
> xterm

$ xterm bash
$ echo $TERM
> xterm

$ xterm zsh
$ echo $TERM
> xterm
```

At least, this is not specifically due to Gnome Terminal, as it's the same with Xterm. I have to add the `export TERM="xterm-256color"` in the shell's profiles.

I had a similar issue with exporting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from `.profile`, which was always overwritten (I don't remember how I solved it).

What overwrites/prevents exporting of the `TERM` environment variable from `.profile`, and why?

### Notes (update)

After Muru's comment, I tried this: `gnome-terminal --command="[sh/bash/zsh] -l"` and `xterm -ls [sh/bash/zsh]` (by `[sh/bash/zsh]` I mean replace in turn by each), to get a login shell (but it did not ask for a password, funny), and the result differs: I get `TERM="xterm-256color"` with Sh and Bash, but not with Zsh, with which I always get `TERM="xterm"`.

Comment: Did you try running those shells as login shells? (`bash -l`, for example)

Comment: @muru, I just tried these: `gnome-terminal --command="[sh/bash/zsh] -l"` and `xterm -ls [sh/bash/zsh]`. Indeed, this makes a difference (will add it as a comment in the question's post). With Sh and Bash, I get `xterm-256color` as exported from `.profile`, but with Zsh, I still get `xterm`.

Answer (score 1):

`~/.profile` is typically run by login shells, so `sh`,`bash`, and `zsh` do not process it when called normally. Invoking them by using the `-l` option makes them login shells, and results in sourcing of `~/.profile`. `zsh` does not use `~/.profile`, but `~/.zprofile`, because of [incompatibilities with other `sh` syntax](https://superuser.com/questions/187639/zsh-not-hitting-profile).

Most terminals have an option to run shells as login shells (at least GNOME Terminal, XFCE4 Terminal and Terminator do). You can enable that (if you make frequent changes to the `profile`s, or simply log out and log back in.

Further reading:

- [What's the difference between .bashrc, .bash_profile, and .environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment)
- [Difference between .bashrc and .bash_profile](https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile)

Comment: Yes, but `~/.profile` should define the environment variables which the non‑longin shells should inherit. There are other exported environment variable in there, and they are inherited by the shells; so the `TERM` variable seems to be subject to a specific treatment. I did not knew for `~/.zprofile`, thanks for the note.

Comment: @Hibou57 Did you log out and login? That's required for changes to `~/.profile` to take effect if not in a login shell.

Comment: Yes, I did (even some reboots). I will have another test later tomorrow, with applications others than shells.